# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hideturtle' ??? What does that mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

There is an error in my code. I do not know how to fix this.
It is supposed to create a game that you need to shoot the yellow blocks.

Can anyone please help me?
This is the whole code.

```
    import turtle as te
    from turtle import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import time as t
    from time import *

    window = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=750, height=500, bg="sky blue")
    canvas.pack()

    ground = canvas.create_rectangle(750, 100, 0, 0, fill="SpringGreen2")
    canvas.move(ground, 0, 400)

    ball = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 10, 10, fill="deep pink")
    canvas.move(ball, 750/3.5 + 50, 0+17 + 190)

    shooter = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 0, 0, fill="blue2")
    canvas.move(shooter, 750/3.5, 0+17 + 200)

    castle = canvas.create_rectangle(750/3.5, 500/1.5, 0, 0, fill="gray60")
    canvas.move(castle, 0, 400-500/1.5)

    power = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 0, 0, fill="gray60")
    canvas.move(power, 400, 40)

    Bird = canvas.create_rectangle(60, 30, 0, 0, fill="gold")
    canvas.move(Bird, 650, 50)

    Birda = canvas.create_rectangle(60, 30, 0, 0, fill="gold")
    canvas.move(Birda, 650, 50)

    Birdb = canvas.create_rectangle(60, 30, 0, 0, fill="gold")
    canvas.move(Birdb, 650, 50)

    Birdc = canvas.create_rectangle(60, 30, 0, 0, fill="gold")
    canvas.move(Birdc, 650, 50)

    Lives = 3
    def part_one():
        Bird.hideturtle()
        Birda.hideturtle
        Birdb.hideturtle()
        Birdc.hideturtle()
```

This is all needed to create the same error

Answer (score 0):

`Bird` and `Birda` through `Birdc` are `Canvas` item IDs (`int`) which allow you to ask the `canvas` to modify the graphic elements they identify (rectangles in this case.)  None of them respond the `hideturtle()` method as they aren't turtle instances.  You haven't created any turtle instances.  So far in your code, it's not clear why you `import` turtle (twice.)

Comment: So what should it be?

Comment: @P4-1RAMESHLOHAN, what it should be depends on what you're trying to do -- edit your question and explain a little further so that someone can help you.  Or, you can start another question as this one has been answered in that the error message has been explained.